# Много мониторов + ноутбук

Tags: ноутбук, монитор

Хочу выбрать ноутбук(ультрабук 13'), проинсталить Kubuntu и подключить 3 монитира. Сейчас использую ноут с 2 внешними мониторами, но у ноутбука Nvidia карта с 2 выходами. Если ноут будет с карточкой 620? Нужен совет как лучше решить эту проблему ?

Comment: Можно использовать USB видеокарту

Answer (score 1):

Решил через USB-C порт и коробку распределитель.